# Setting up flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and having problem running flutter doctor. I have extracted the files in another folder and tried setting the path, echo $PATH gives

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

but still on running `flutter doctor` it says

> flutter command is not found

Anybody who can help please ?

Comment: I can't see anything from Flutter in the path.

Comment: How did you try to set the path?

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin I tried this

Answer (score 3):

Flutter is not yet set in your PATH.
Try:
Step 1:

```
sudo nano .profile
```

Step 2:

```
export PATH="<Path To extracted Flutter directory>/bin:$PATH"
```

Step 3:

```
source .profile
```

Comment: Does `echo $PATH` now show the flutter directory/bin in your path?  If not, try closing and reopening the window, or at worst, log out and log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [official link](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos) how to setup flutter environment

1. Download flutter.zip
2. Extract the file in the desired location, for example:

   `cd ~/development
   unzip ~/Downloads/flutter_macos_v1.0.0-stable.zip`
3. Add the flutter tool to your path:

   `` export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin ``

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are in ubuntu in terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

then add to the end of the file

```
export PATH=$PATH:`path to your extracted flutter directory`/flutter/bin
```

Then logout and login or restart

then

if you see `flutter/bin` in your path it will work. Hop it helps

Answer (score 0):

try this, i hope it can help,

(in terminal)

first,

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH)
```

secondly,

```
export PATH="$PATH:<Flutter directory>/flutter/bin"
```