# flutter error on ubuntu 18.04 'flutter' command not found

Tags: flutter, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install flutter on ubuntu 18.04. After downloading the flutter package from [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux), I set the PATH variables, after that whenever I try to execute `flutter` on terminal it was giving an error `command not found`.

Even I try to execute flutter command inside `flutter/bin` the result remains the same!

I tried to restart and check then also result remains the same.

This is how my **.bash_profile** looks like

```sh
rajath@rajath-Inspiron:~/Downloads/flutter/bin$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/Android
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export PATH=/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

**Error log:**

```sh
rajath@rajath-Inspiron:~/Downloads/flutter/bin$ flutter doctor
flutter: command not found
rajath@rajath-Inspiron:~/Downloads/flutter/bin$ flutter
flutter: command not found
rajath@rajath-Inspiron:~/Downloads/flutter/bin$
```

*Any kind of help will much much appreciated!!!*

Comment: try: rajath@rajath-Inspiron:~/Downloads/flutter/bin$ **./flutter doctor**

Comment: by the way why my env PATH are not working?

Comment: basically your `PATH` is incorrect: `export PATH= ~/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH` - notice **~** before `/Downloads/...`

Comment: needs to restart after this?

Comment: no, just reload your `.bash_profile`

Comment: Many thanks bro! is this `~/Downloads/flutter` is the ideal space to flutter right?

Comment: `Downloads`? not really, see https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux

Comment: try this, I think the answer is the same, hopefully useful,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58539293/9363835

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `export PATH=$PATH:~/Downloads/flutter/bin` to your `~/.bashrc`.

That will add the flutter path to your path variable everytime you start a new bash.

And maybe you should install flutter anywhere near `/usr/`

Answer (score 0):

As worldpotato said, You must add to your .bashrc file (or .bash_profile)

You can run the command

`echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/Downloads/flutter/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc`

and

`echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/Downloads/flutter/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile`